# Android: Drawable Image as src for img tag in a string

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview, android-file

**Update:**
I would like to avoid using webview altogether if possible.

I am working on a project that will take a string that is filled with html code and then write it to an html file and then that file will be emailed to the user. The problem I am having is that I would like to add images to the html string by referencing the image from the drawable folder such that my code looks like this:

```
String html = "more html tags" + "<img src=\" my drawable image \" />" + "more html tags";
```

I have tried solving this issue in many different ways including using webview (even though my project does not need to display the html in app, the html just needs to be written to the file. So is webview pointless for this?), but nothing seems to work.

So is it possible to add an image to an html string like the way I have above?

Comment: Is I have clearly understand? You want to inline image into html so after the html was sent any recipient can saw the image on any device.

Comment: yes it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save required image as separated file to public directory.

You can't use your drawable because other applications (browser for example) havn't access to your app's drawables.

Comment: Could you explain more? I am writing the html to a file which then is shared with the email app, I am not actually sharing the images with another app, just the html file.

Comment: While you didn't share images with another app then another app can't show the images which you have added to html.